# Errors while creating object using simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

i'm creating comments to post using simple form. It looks like this:

> views/posts/show.html.slim

```
# ...

- if user_signed_in?
  .row
    .columns
      h2 Add a comment:

  .row
    .medium-5.columns
      = simple_form_for [post, comment] do |f|
        = f.error_notification

        .form-inputs
          = f.input :body

        .form-actions
          = f.button :submit
```

Also I have a validation in comments model:

```
validates :body, presence: true
```

When I try to create empty comment I need to get errors under the fields.
Here is should be ***'can't be blank'*** under the body comment field

Here is my comments controller (I'm using responders and decent_exposure)

> comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :create
  before_action :authorize_user!, only: :destroy

  expose :post
  expose_decorated :comment

  def create
    comment.post = post
    comment.user = current_user
    if comment.save
      respond_with comment, location: post
    else
      # I should to write here something but I don't know what
    end
  end

  def destroy
    comment.destroy
    respond_with comment, location: post
  end

  private

  def authorize_user!
    authorize(comment, :manage?)
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
  end
end
```

I dont know should I check comment.save like this or not? If yes, what should I write to else?

Comment: You can render the same form with errors in else part if you want

Comment: @bluefoggy I tried to put render "posts/show", but it didn't work

Comment: Check if you can access the errors in your view by printing comment.errors.full_messages.

Comment: @bluefoggy yes, i got it